# How to get a google maps link to email from a geocode?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocode

I can't seem to find this anywhere. How do I request the Google Maps API to give me a Google Maps Hyperlink from a geocode?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a geocode via the Maps API just set up a script that can retrieve the lat/long and adds it to the maps.google.com query url.

maps.google.com query url's look like this http://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.0625,-95.677068